# MFMailComposeViewController crash in iOS6

Tags: ios6, crash, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I use MFMailComposeViewController in my project, and everything is ok but running in iOS6. Would someone please give me a hand ?

[image: code snapshot]
[image: callstack snapshot]

Comment: what's the compiler warning that Xcode is showing next to your breakpoint?  :-)  If I had to guess, it *looks* like the MFMailComposeViewController you're initializing there lives only within the scope of those "{" & "}" brackets.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Thank you very much! I found out why this crash generate, It's my neglect. I replaced the 'methodSignatureForSelector:' of NSObject, and the logic is incorrect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this crash generate, It's my neglect. I replaced the `methodSignatureForSelector:` of `NSObject`, and the logic is incorrect!